# Get root privileges in android app for a rooted device?

Tags: android, android-file

How to get root access or permissions for an app which copies files from assets folder to /etc and other folders which are normally not accessible on non-rooted device.

I wrote following code but as it turns out it doesn't produce any error as well as doesn't perform the desired action. 
Do I need to edit something in manifest?

```
public class CopyFilesFromApkToSystemActivity extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */

    private static final String FILE1 = "usb_modeswitch.conf";
    private static final String FILE2 = "usb_modeswitch";
    private static final String FILE3 = "gprs";
    private static final String FILE4 = "ip-up";
    private static final String FILE5 = "cdma.sh";

    private static String PATH1 = "/etc/";
    private static String PATH2 = "/system/xbin/";
    private static String PATH3 = "/etc/ppp/peers/";
    private static String PATH4 = "/etc/ppp/";
    private static String PATH5 = "/system/xbin/";

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        Toast.makeText(this, "Copy started", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        try {
            copyfile(FILE1,PATH1);
            copyfile(FILE2,PATH2);
            copyfile(FILE3,PATH3);
            copyfile(FILE4,PATH4);
            copyfile(FILE5,PATH5);



        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }




    }

    private void copyfile(String fileName, String pathName) throws IOException {

        InputStream mInput = this.getAssets().open(fileName);
        String outFileName = fileName + pathName;
        OutputStream mOutput = new FileOutputStream(outFileName);
        byte[] mBuffer = new byte[1024];
        int mLength;
        while ((mLength = mInput.read(mBuffer))>0)
        {
            mOutput.write(mBuffer, 0, mLength);
        }
        mOutput.flush();
        mOutput.close();
        mInput.close();

        //Toast.makeText(this, fileName + " copied", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Someone wrote a specific class to gain root privilege, you can check this:
http://muzikant-android.blogspot.ca/2011/02/how-to-get-root-access-and-execute.html

Answer (score 0):

Might be a issue of permissions on folders  . Set permission on your folders before you start to copy and try

```
try {
                Runtime.getRuntime().exec("chmod 777 /etc/");
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```

Comment: add these also..still not copying files

Comment: if it is an external storage location I hope u added 
   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />    in manifest plus add  log in your catch block

Comment: I am shipping files in apk and those will be written in /etc and other system folders. Now?